# conditional logic not working in haml

Tags: ruby, if-statement, sinatra, haml

I have a HAML template that looks like the following (also using Sinatra, not sure if that is important):

```
- @email = params[:email]
EMAIL: x#{@email}#{params[:email]}#{@email.to_s.empty?}x

-if #{@email.to_s.empty?}
  %form{ :action => "/", :method => "post"}
    %fieldset
      %input{:type => "text", :name => "email", :class => "text"}           
      %input{:type => "submit", :value => "Notify me!", :class => "button"}
-else
  Thank you for your interest!
```

I have the top output there for debugging.  When I load the page initially, I see "EMAIL: xtruex" and the form, indicating that the parameter is empty... all working as planned.

Now when I fill in "testing@gmail.com" in the form and click the button, it redirects back to "/" and I see "EMAIL: xtesting@gmail.comtesting@gmail.comfalsex"  which tells me that my conditional logic should work.

But I still see the form, my else statement is not being executed... the if statement is still being triggered.

I'm guessing it's a simple formatting issue.  Can someone assist?

Just in case it's needed, my Sinatra app file is simple:

```
get '/' do
  haml :index
end

post '/' do
  User.create(:email => params["email"])
  haml :index
end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this if statement will always be true

```
-if #{@email.to_s.empty?}
```

that's because you are creating a string with `#{}` and only nil and false will flip the if.

so you need to write something like

```
-if @email.blank?
```

UPDATE:

this is not quite right, have a look the comment of @matt

Comment: That's what I had initially but when I do that, I get: undefined method `blank?' for nil:NilClass

Comment: OK, so I got it but I'm still a little confused.  I didn't realize you created a string with `#{}` so that was part of the issue.  I changed my if to `-if params[:email].to_s.empty?` but why do I need to do to_s on that?

Comment: might be the case that sinatra does not provide a blank? method. use nil? instead

Comment: Going to mark this as the answer... even though it wasn't the exact answer to my problem, it lead me in the right direction which is very appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: This isn‘t _quite_ right. In `-if #{@email.to_s.empty?}`, `#` is a comment charater, so the line is effectively just `if`. The conditional is then whatever is on the next line (`%form...` etc.), which when the Haml is compiled is a call to [`Buffer#push_text`](https://github.com/haml/haml/blob/3.1.6/lib/haml/buffer.rb#L111). This is therefore always executed, and returns a true value, so the (now empty) true branch is always executed.The overall effect is as if `#{@email.to_s.empty?}` evalualates to true, and the fix is the same, but the reality is a little more subtle.

Comment: @matt you are right. i was thinking about inline ruby interpolation, but through ```-``` it's already a ruby block: http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#ruby_interpolation_